# Accumulative sum daily wise total

Tags: sql-server-2008

`fsv_whdtwiseporductstock` Table

```
Prodcode           In_stock    DOC_DT    
C-AW1104HB47300     10          01/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     40          01/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     50          01/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     10          02/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     20          04/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     10          07/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     5           07/08/2015
```

Desired Output

```
Prodcode              Doc_dt        Cumulative
C-AW1104HB47300       01/08/2015    100
C-AW1104HB47300       02/08/2015    110
C-AW1104HB47300       03/08/2015    110
C-AW1104HB47300       04/08/2015    130
C-AW1104HB47300       05/08/2015    130
C-AW1104HB47300       06/08/2015    130
C-AW1104HB47300       07/08/2015    145
```

What I did

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY PRODCODE, [DOC_DT]) AS rownum,* 
FROM FSV_WHDTWISEPRODUCTSTOCK
)

SELECT a.PRODCODE, a.DOC_DT, a.IN_STOCK, SUM(b.IN_STOCK) AS Cumulative
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b ON a.PRODCODE = b.PRODCODE AND b.rownum <= a.rownum
where a.prodcode like 'C-AW1104HB47300'
GROUP BY a.PRODCODE, a.rownum, a.[DOC_DT], a.IN_STOCK
ORDER BY a.PRODCODE, a.[DOC_DT]
```

Current output

```
Prodcode           In_stock    DOC_DT    
C-AW1104HB47300     10          01/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     40          01/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     50          01/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     10          02/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     20          04/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     10          07/08/2015
C-AW1104HB47300     5           07/08/2015
```

Comment: Change the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` to match your desired output.

Comment: Hi Jody, than you for your reply, but i really cant make it work i tried a lot. I am just new in sql qery.  thanks